# Grails Spring Security Core Plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security

I am (finally) upgrading my Acegi plugin to Spring Security Core. At the same time, I am upgrading from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.0. My site was fully functional before, but now when I try to get to my default page (which is `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`) I am redirected to the `auth` action of my `LoginController`. This method was never invoked with Acegi, so I don't know what the problem is. Have I set up my configuration wrong or is there something else I need to be thinking about?

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap

    grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap  = [
                '/blog/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/static/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/consensus/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
                '/login/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/signup/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/home/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
                '/test/**':['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                '/admin/**':['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                '/adminmanage/**':['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                '/quartz/**':['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                '/**/*.css':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/js/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/images/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/monitoring**':['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                '/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
            ]
```

My UrlMappings.groovy is:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/"(controller:"x", action:"y")
        "/z/?"(controller:"x", action:"y")
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"
                {
                    constraints {
                        // apply constraints here
                    }
                }
        "500"(view: '/error')
    }
}
```

I have been reading through the documentation but am having some problems, so I am not sure if there is more relevant code one would need to see. If there is, please let me know and I will add it. Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure `'/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']` is what is causing it, withing quite remembering how the presedence rules works for the config map way of doing things (I use controller annotations).

Try removing the line just to see if you can reach your main page then. If you can, you need to figure out how to not make it conflict.

Good luck!

Comment: @Oliv Thanks - removing the last one helped me debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other options in my `Config.groovy` were incorrect and this caused the problem. Once I corrected them everything worked fine.

Despite it being called out in the documentation, I had security fields that were not prepended with `grails.plugins.springsecurity` This caused the engine not to recognize them, which for some reason resulted in the call to `auth`.

Comment: Could you edit-elaborate what the issue was? If there is something unclear in the docs or something that might be useful to put in there it would be nice to know. (Or if other people hits this problem and end up here via google only to find out that you solved the problem and nothing else ;) )

Comment: @Oliver - The problem seems really specific to me or I would have done so. I'll do it anyway though - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After remove openid plugin all requests redirects me to the login page! I don't know what to do... I've already remove everything related.